# inquirer responses used in inserted to database with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, variables, inquirer

So I've done quite a bit of digging on this one but can't seem to get my variables to INSERT INTO my database.

my goal is to allow the user to add an employee via inquirer npm

My attempt:

```
).then(function ({ first_name, last_name, manager }) {
            connection.query("INSERT INTO employee (first_name, last_name, manager) 
                 VALUES ?", [first_name, last_name, manager], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
})
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Just a syntax error, I needed quotes around the values

```
).then(function ({ first_name, last_name, manager }) {
            connection.query("INSERT INTO employee (first_name, last_name, manager) 
                 VALUES ?", ('first_name', 'last_name', 'manager'), function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
})
```